# AI - Adding properties to layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, alignment, html

I am exporting my image from AI as html and would like it to stay centered on the canvas as the browser changes size. I heard that you can add attributes to the layer by changing the name of the layer. How do I do that and can you suggest a link that gives a list of attributes?

Comment: I'm afraid the layer properties you have mentioned are not a common feature of Ai...

Answer (score 2):

That is not a feature of Illustrator. You are perhaps confusing this with Photoshop's [Generator feature](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28732/1286), which will save layers automatically as images, if they are named in a certain way.

Keeping an image centered in the browser window is done with a CSS style or javascript.